# Unwrap a Frequency Table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe A that looks like this

```
value   Frequency

0.1        3
0.2        2
```

and I want to convert it to dataframe B like below

```
Sample

0.1
0.1
0.1
0.2
0.2
```

Simply put, dataframe A is the samples and their frequency (repetition). Dataframe B is literally expanding that. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

what I did (minimal working example reproducing above):

```
X = pd.DataFrame([(0.1,3),(0.2,2)],columns=['value','Frequency'])
Sample = list()
for index, row in X.iterrows():
    Value = row['value']
    Freq = int(row['Frequency'])
    Sample = Sample + [Value]*Freq
Data = pd.DataFrame({'Sample':pd.Series(Sample)})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Series.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html), where the `repeats` argument can also be a series of ints:

```
df.value.repeat(df.Frequency).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('Sample')

   Sample
0     0.1
1     0.1
2     0.1
3     0.2
4     0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html)

```
>>> df['value'].repeat(df.Frequency)
0    0.1
0    0.1
0    0.1
1    0.2
1    0.2
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Or Create new dataframe with

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df['value'].repeat(df.Frequency).to_numpy(),columns=["Sample"])

   Sample
0     0.1
1     0.1
2     0.1
3     0.2
4     0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***reindex + repeat***

```
X = X.reindex(X.index.repeat(X.Frequency))
```